# Compare 2 multidimensional arrays using loops

Tags: python, loops, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've been tasked to compare 2 sets of data, each stored in 2 separate csv files. They both contain 2 columns with around several thousand entries. I've filled 2 separate arrays, but now I want to compare 1 column from each array. Im completely green to python and  getting very confused about the best way to compare the 2 arrays.

Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np 
with open ('Flight_3_GPS.csv', 'r') as f:
    GPS = [] #create an empty list
    for line in f:
        GPS.append([float(i) for i in line.strip('\n').split(',')])
    GPS = np.transpose(GPS)
    #print(GPS[0][87]) #[column][row]

with open ('Flight_3_V_Data.csv', 'r') as f:
    Data = [] #create an empty list
    for line in f:
        Data.append([float(i) for i in line.strip('\n').split(',')])
    Data = np.transpose(Data)
    #print(Data[1][56]) #[column][row]

i=0
j=0
for i in GPS[i,1]:
    for j in Data[j,1]:
        if i == j:
           print(j)
           print(i)
```

So if the first 2 rows don't match, then the loop moves on to compare the next pair of rows

Thanks

---

Comment: So you want *element-wise* comparison: a list of booleans specifying whether the *i*-th row is equal in both files?

Comment: what error and/or unexpected output are you getting?

Comment: yeah so if my 2 arrays are: [A,B] and [C,D]. I want to set it up such that if B and C are equal, then I can eventually find a value for A

Answer (score 1):

be careful, in python, your first column is 0 not 1.

```
for i,val_gps in enumarate(GPS[:,0]): 
    if val_gps == Data[i,0]:
       print('GPSindex ' + str(i) + ' : ' + str(val_gps) ' matches with  dataindex ' + str(i) + ' : ' + str(Data[i,0]))
```

Comment: ok cool, I ran the code and its now telling me theres an 'unexpected EOF while parsing'...

Comment: Ho, I missed a ) at the end of the print line. Sorry about that